# How can I solve the "property does not exist"-problem in TypeScript when using lowdb?

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, lowdb

I have the following code for reading from a JSON-file using lowdb which works, but I get the TypeScript warning "Property 'entries' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)" or "Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)"

```
import { Low } from 'lowdb'
import { JSONFile } from 'lowdb/node'

const adapter = new JSONFile('db.json')
const db = new Low(adapter, { entries: [] })

await db.read()
const { entries } = db.data // destructure
entries.push({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Entry'
})
console.log('entries:', entries[0])
```

Is this a problem of the VSCode linter I could ignore or should I solve it? And if so, how?

I have tried to not destructure the `db.data.entries` object, but the warning stays the same. I also tried to not initialize the lowdb with this specific default array, but the problem stays the same when initializing with `const db = new Low(adapter, {})` instead.

There is also no "Quick Fix" option available in VSCode.

According to the README of [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) this should just work, so I assume a problem in my dev environment. The code is running in a Svelte 4 environment under src/lib/mylib.ts.

Any ideas solving the issue are most welcome. So far I did not ask ChatGPT about it, but I'll have a try in the meantime.

Comment: Try: `new JSONFile<{ entries: any[] }>('db.json')`

Comment: @Konrad: Thx, that helped. I think, I begin to understand how this kind of typing works. **[=**